# Getting extrinsics from AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, avfoundation, truedepth-camera

I'am currently struggling to get extrinsic matrices while recording depth video using TrueDepth camera in AVFoundation.

Here's how i get my extrinsics inside depthDataOutput function:

```
if let calibrationData = depthData.cameraCalibrationData{
    let extrinsicMatrix = calibrationData.extrinsicMatrix
}
```

When i print the extrinsicMatrix i only get identity matrix. Is there a way to get actual extrinsics without ARKit or this method (.extrinsicMatrix) just does not work at all?